# Design a subnet

Tags: networking

```
A company is granted a static address 192.168.10.0.
The Company wants to have four subnets for four of its departments. Each Department is having 50-60 computers.
Design Subnetwork using sub netting concepts.
Identify Number of IP addresses on required in each Subnetwork.
Write their starting and ending addresses.
```

I am not getting, how to approach this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it, especially in the [second answer part](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53995/8499), but you must understand all the information in the first answer part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company is granted a static address of 192.168.10.0. The company wants to have four subnets for four of its departments. Each department is having 50-60 computers.

To design the subnetwork, we will use the subnetting concepts. The company has been granted a static address of 192.168.10.0. This is a Class C IP address. The first octet (192) is the network address and the last three octets (168.10.0) are the host addresses.

To create four subnets, we will need to borrow two bits from the host addresses. This will give us four subnets, each with 62 host addresses. The first subnet will have the network address of 192.168.10.0 and the last subnet will have the network address of 192.168.10.192.

The first subnet will have the starting address of 192.168.10.1 and the ending address of 192.168.10.62.

The second subnet will have the starting address of 192.168.10.65 and the ending address of 192.168.10.126.

The third subnet will have the starting address of 192.168.10.129 and the ending address of 192.168.10.190.

The fourth subnet will have the starting address of 192.168.10.193 and the ending address of 192.168.10.254.